# Python3: Files organizing

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I got this path of file on Unix system:

```
Folder1/Folder2/text.txt
```

Folder1 contains only Folder2, and Folder2 contains the file. So the path to the file test.txt can be shorter -> Folder1/text.txt, I need some universal solution:

```
if(folder contains only one subfolder)-> move files from subfolder to folder and del subfolder
```

Comment: And what is the question, what you've tried to do?

Comment: If someone gives me something like this: /Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/file, I dont want to click 3x times in file explorer to get file, but only one time -> Folder1/file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment I see you want to move files in Folder3 as well as Folder2. Here is a program that will move all files in all folders below Folder1, then delete the folders (but not Folder1.) First you have to change directory Folder1. And if any of the files you want to move exist in Folder1 already, you will get an error message. You can fix this though. I put in some print statements so you can see it working.

```
import os, shutil
p = os.path._getfullpathname("Folder1")
print p
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(p, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        k = os.path.join(root,file)
        print k
        shutil.move(k, p)
    for dir in dirs:
        k = os.path.join(root,dir)
        print k
        os.rmdir(k)
```